# Error in plsql . here flag has value 1 or no data. when no data i have to insert somethings but error coming.suggestions please

Tags: sql, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY BAS_NUMB_UPD AS
PROCEDURE BAS_NUM_UPDN AS
CURSOR cur IS
    SELECT DISTINCT o.obj_id,LTRIM(substr(convert_171_to_711(cp.T_C_CP),1,7),'0')  bas_n
      FROM t_obj o, mat_tea_rel mpr, coorg_tea cp
     WHERE o.obj_type = 'Resin' 
       AND o.obj_id = mpr.obj_id
       AND mpr.p_k_id = cp.p_k_id;

    l_b_num_attr_id  number(10) := get_attribute_id('Ba Nu');
    flag1 VARCHAR2(10);

    BEGIN
        FOR x IN cur LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line(x.obj_id||'contains b n'||x.bas_n);
            SELECT flag INTO flag1
              FROM t_xc_s_values
             WHERE attr_id = l_b_num_attr_id 
               AND Obj_id = x.obj_id
               AND VALUE = x.bas_n;

            EXCEPTION 
               WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
                  flag1 :='Nothing'; 
               WHEN OTHERS THEN
                   raise_application_error(-20011,'Unknown Exception in PROCEDURE');
            END;

            IF flag1 = 1 THEN 
                dbms_output.put_line('flag equal to one');
            ELSE
                INSERT INTO t_xc_s_values (obj_id, at_id, VALUE,)
                VALUES (x.obj_id, l_b_num_attr_id, x.bas_n);
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
    END;
    END BAS_NUM_UPDN;
END BAS_NUMB_UPD;
```

These are the errors

> Error(28,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" when
>   expecting one of the following:     begin case declare end exit for
>   goto if loop mod null pragma    raise return select update while with
>         <<    close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
>   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe
>
> Error(35,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one
>   of the following:     end not pragma final instantiable order
>   overriding static    member constructor map
>
> Error(47,3): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting
>   one of the following:     ;

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not properly nested:

- If you have an EXCEPTION part, you need to have the triple BEGIN / EXCEPTION / END on the same level. So you probably need to insert a BEGIN after LOOP.
- Each END must match a BEGIN. Besides the missing BEGIN mention before, you have too many END statements at the end. Remove the one on the third last line.

These are just syntactical errors. I didn't check whether the procedure does what you intend.

Comment: It would also be a good idea to initialise flag1 and to remove  dbms_output.put_line from productionized code.

Answer (score 1):

The errors you get are quite straightforward. You have an `EXCEPTION ... END` but no matching `BEGIN`. You want to trap the no_data_found for your flag select, so start that block with a `BEGIN`

(Why would you use a WHEN OTHERS? Why would you trap it and then say it is 'Unknown'? The error is never unknown.)

```
BEGIN
     FOR x IN cur LOOP
         dbms_output.put_line(x.obj_id||'contains b n'||x.bas_n);
         BEGIN -- added here
           SELECT flag INTO flag1
             FROM t_xc_s_values
            WHERE attr_id = l_b_num_attr_id
              AND Obj_id = x.obj_id
              AND VALUE = x.bas_n;
          EXCEPTION
             WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                flag1 :='Nothing';
             WHEN OTHERS THEN
                raise_application_error(-20011,'Unknown Exception in PROCEDURE');
         END;
```

Next error:
your insert statement has one comma too many:

```
INSERT INTO t_xc_s_values (obj_id, at_id, VALUE,)
```

Next error:
one `END` too many

```
    END LOOP;
    END;  -- this will END your procedure block
    END BAS_NUM_UPDN; -- this will complain it has to match the procedure begin
```

Your PLSQL code is also unnecessary. You could write your logic as a SQL statement, improving your performance.

```
PROCEDURE BAS_NUM_UPDN AS 
IS
   l_b_num_attr_id  number(10) := get_attribute_id('Ba Nu');
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO t_xc_s_values (obj_id, at_id, VALUE)
   SELECT DISTINCT o.obj_id,
                   l_b_num_attr_id,
                   LTRIM(substr(convert_171_to_711(cp.T_C_CP),1,7),'0') bas_n
     FROM t_obj o, mat_tea_rel mpr, coorg_tea cp
    WHERE o.obj_type = 'Resin'
      AND o.obj_id = mpr.obj_id
      AND mpr.p_k_id = cp.p_k_id;
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT flag
                        FROM t_xc_s_values
                       WHERE attr_id = l_b_num_attr_id
                         AND Obj_id = o.obj_id
                         AND VALUE = LTRIM(substr(convert_171_to_711(cp.T_C_CP),1,7),'0'));           
END;
```